# .each() two different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to compare 2 inputs with different class in rows but same classes in columns. i tried that `.each` but im having an error. On specifying the `amount_remaining` class

**Uncaught TypeError: $('.amount_remaining')[i].val**

```js
var i = 0;
$(document).on('click','#sub',function(){
  $('.amount_paid').each(function(){
var val_paid = $(this).val();
  if(val_paid > $('.amount_remaining')[i].val())
  {
     console.log("Something is Greater Than");
  }
  else
  {
     console.log("Something is Less Than");
  }

  i++;
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input class = 'amount_paid' type = 'number'></td>
  <td><input class = 'amount_remaining' type = 'number'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input class = 'amount_paid' type = 'number'></td>
  <td><input class = 'amount_remaining' type = 'number'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input class = 'amount_paid' type = 'number'></td>
  <td><input class = 'amount_remaining' type = 'number'></td>
</tr>
</table>

<button id = 'sub'>SUBMIT</button>
```

Comment: What's the error? EDIT: Never mind, ran the snippet. But it'd be convenient to include it in your post as well :)

Comment: @kingdaro my bad. just editted it and i think the second selector is the error. i dont know how to properly index the `amount_remaining` input

Comment: `if(val_paid > $(this).closest("tr").find('.amount_remaining').val())`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat thank you. saved a lot of time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting the error because of the way you are accessing one element from `$('.amount_remaining')` element list.
You should either use `$('.amount_remaining')[i].value` or `$('.amount_remaining').eq(i).val()`.

See the code below.

```js
var i = 0;
$(document).on('click','#sub',function(){
  $('.amount_paid').each(function(){
var val_paid = $(this).val();
  if(val_paid > $('.amount_remaining').eq(i).val())
  {
     console.log("Something is Greater Than");
  }
  else
  {
     console.log("Something is Less Than");
  }

  i++;
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input class = 'amount_paid' type = 'number'></td>
  <td><input class = 'amount_remaining' type = 'number'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input class = 'amount_paid' type = 'number'></td>
  <td><input class = 'amount_remaining' type = 'number'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input class = 'amount_paid' type = 'number'></td>
  <td><input class = 'amount_remaining' type = 'number'></td>
</tr>
</table>

<button id = 'sub'>SUBMIT</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Aniket's answer is correct is working too but i think i will use this, lesser code.

Comment: Aniket's answer is a different approach to get the result. I just pointed out the mistake in your code. You already had the code almost working.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working sample for you problem.

```js
var i = 0;
$(document).on('click','#sub',function(){
var lstAmtpaid =   $('.amount_paid');
var lstAmtremaining = $('.amount_remaining');

  var inpitLength = lstAmtpaid.length;  
  while (i < inpitLength)
  {
  console.log($($('.amount_paid')[0]).val())
  
  if($(lstAmtpaid[i]).val() > $(lstAmtremaining[i]).val())
  {
     console.log("Something is Greater Than");
  }
  else
  {
     console.log("Something is Less Than");
  }

  i++;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input class = 'amount_paid' type = 'number'></td>
  <td><input class = 'amount_remaining' type = 'number'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input class = 'amount_paid' type = 'number'></td>
  <td><input class = 'amount_remaining' type = 'number'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input class = 'amount_paid' type = 'number'></td>
  <td><input class = 'amount_remaining' type = 'number'></td>
</tr>
</table>

<button id = 'sub'>SUBMIT</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, you can use [`.get(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/#get1) to get an index of an element from a jQuery object.